# PHP array_sum and groupBy

Tags: php, arrays

I need to groupBy and count my input from my user,

 For example I have a array set of :
[ "1","2","3","3","5"] How can I group the same input and count it generate a new array with count of same group, the generated output I need is this a multi dimensional array with groupby like tihs

```
    ID - Count
    ['1']['1']
    ['2']['1']
    ['3']['2']
    ['5']['1']
```

I tried using this

```
$result = array();
foreach ($products as $key => $element) {
    $result=$element[$key]= $element;
     dd($result);
}
```

But its not counting properly

Comment: Yep. There's a [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) for that.

Comment: It works thank @Mike

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to do

```
    $myarray = array(1,2,3,3,4);

    $result_array = array();
    foreach($myarray as $key=>$item){   
        if(isset($result_array[$item])){        
            $result_array[$item] = $result_array[$item]+1;
        }else{      
            $result_array[$item]= 1;        
        }
    }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result as

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 1
)
```